# Accesing the DAM path to view the uploaded file getting 404 error

Tags: adobe, aem

I've uploaded some files in DAM path in CRXDE, when i try to access the file using the path, I'm able to open the file, but when i try to open the same file again I'm getting 404 error.And also in rare cases when i try to open first time itself I'm getting 404 error. But the file is available in crxde(PFA). In local i never faced any issue like 404, but in other environment I'm facing the issue.
Is might be due to server replication ?

** JSP Code:-**

```
<td><a href="${podfiles.path}">
    <img src="../images/pdf.png"style="width: 20px;">
</a></td>  // where,  ${podfiles.path} -->/content/dam/nextgen/EHUB-POD/IN/2.pdf
```

Comment: Is it on the Author or Publisher? 404 can also be returned in some cases if you don't have permissions to the path. Can you check the permissions?

Comment: Hi,  But all the access are given for that user, in DAM path

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: So, just to clarify, on local you see the file. But on a different environment (like publish) you don't see the file. Can you check if the file is replicated as the screenshot does not say that the problem in on server where the file exists.

Comment: Hi, can you say how to check whether the file is replicated or not in other environment

Comment: Open crx/de in the environment (like publisher) and check if the file/node exists. Also, on author, you can see the last published date in properties of the node using crx.

Comment: The file node exists (publish & author ) side.  But when im logged in with any user , getting 404 but in new browser , when i copy the path and paste it, im able to view the file, where that should not happen

Comment: By new browser do you mean when you are not logged in? In that case, check if anonymous access is allowed on the node. Everyone group needs permission on the node. By default /content/dam is not allowed for anonymous access.

Comment: yes, in new browser, with the same url im able to see the uploaded  pdf file. in crxde, without logging in, im able to see /content/dam/ path with all files uploaded.

Comment: How i can restrict when i try to copy paste the url to open any pdf file.

Comment: Check permissions. Make sure everyone group is not allowed to access paths that you don't want to be accessible without logging in. You can do it via <server>:port/useradmin page (your user administration page)

Comment: Code:-
ResourceResolver resourceResolver;resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
Node pdfJcrNode = resourceResolver.resolve(damPath).adaptTo(Node.class);
NodeIterator dateChildrenNodes; NodeIterator node; dateChildrenNodes = pdfJcrNode.getNodes();
while (dateChildrenNodes.hasNext()) {
Node nextItemNode = dateChildrenNodes.nextNode();node = nextItemNode.getNodes();
while (node.hasNext()) {Node nextItemNode1 = node.nextNode();
POD pod = new POD();String getpath = nextItemNode1.getPath();

Comment: In above code, // getpath
 i'll store in a list and display the path in front end when i click pdf  icon and for some pdf file im able to view it, for some im getting 404, is there any code change do i need to be done, to avoid opening the file in new browser without user loggin

Comment: Please add code in your question so that it's readable. Also, please clarify if you want to list the paths for anonymous users or list all the paths anyway regardless of the logged in user?

Comment: In user admin page, In path /content/dam/.../ehubpod(which i created) /../1.pdf .Here for anonymous user the access is only read only mode,  foe the above path

Comment: Then it means anyone regardless of login can view the file.

Comment: yes. when the url was given in new browser

Comment: Sry, im not able to add code in question, so attached the code.

Comment: Don't use getAdministrativeResourceResolver if this is your component code. Use resource.adaptTo(ResourceResolver.class). This will give you a resource resolver with equivalent permissions for logged in user. Otherwise your code will return all resources and some of them will have permissions others won't.

Comment: So do you mean that i need to give like this,
ResourceResolver resolver = request.getResourceResolver();
  Session session = (Session) resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
......
.....
then logout the session using,
session.save();
session.logout;
after retrieving the data from dam path

Comment: `ResourceResolver resolver = request.getResourceResolver(); ` is ok. You don't need to logout of session

Comment: OK. But one doubt, im not using servlets to retrieve the data, im calling service layer in cq and getting data. so cannot use,  request.getResourceResolver(); can i use suing 'private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;'  like this 
resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(null);

Comment: Don't have enough code to say if that will work (need to see your servlet declaration) but it should be ok.

Comment: Hi, Its working(resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(null); ), this will avoid the viewing the pdf file when we try to copy the url (server name/content/dam/.../Ehub-POD/USVA/POD%20Argentina.pdf ) and paste in new browser . and also 404 issue will be resolved ?

Comment: It should only list files that are allowed. For files which you don't want to allow, change permissions from useradmin.

Comment: mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `getAdministrativeResourceResolver` if this is your component code. Use `resource.adaptTo(ResourceResolver.class)`. This will give you a resource resolver with equivalent permissions for logged in user. Otherwise your code will return all resources and some of them will have permissions others won't.

If your servlet is bound to a path or extension on a resource, you will have access to resource in the servlet and you can get the resource resolver from there. Alternatively you can use `resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(null)`

The resource iterator will give you list of resources according to your permissions. You can then secure the resource access using /useradmin to allow/deny access for anonymous users.